# Responsive box layout

Tags: css, width

I'm doing my personal portfolio website and have run into some problems.

I want to do this (I hope I've explained well enough):
http://itu.dk/people/mbul/portfolio/problem_portfolio.jpg

The black boxes represents the different design cases I've done.

Basically what I'm looking for is to effectively use the full width of the container on different screen sizes and I want it done the most simple and semantic correct way possible :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways. The simplest way probally is making black blocks floating and the sum of the margins and widths should be 100% as follow:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .gray {background-color: #DDD; width: 400px; height: 400px;}
    .black {background-color: #333; width: 40%; height: 40%; float: left; margin-left: 20%;}
    .black.first {margin-left: 0;}
</style>

<div class="gray">
    <div class="black first">

    </div>

    <div class="black">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey man,

Thanks for you input. I actually think I figured it out :-)
http://jsfiddle.net/W74Z8/111/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend centering the boxes `margin:auto;` and giving them a `width:100%;` and a `max-width:300px;`. See what works for you but this might be able to put you in the right direction.